# Test Smart Banner on iOS 8

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, deep-linking, smartbanner

I am attempting to test smart banner deep linking on iOS 8. I used to be able to override the App Store build with a debug build. Now, when I am in mobile Safari, the smart banner says "View" (which takes me to the App Store), instead of "Open".

Has anyone found a good way to debug `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`?

If not, is there a guide where I am able to determine the format of the `url` parameter? For example, if my url is `http://website.com/idea/id123/`, will that be the value of the url automatically, or do I need to put extra parameter's in the smart banner's metadata?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same issue. I registered a urlScheme so I was parsing out @"urlScheme://". It worked with a JS redirect and typing into safari, but seems that Smart Banners aren't working with the code. No idea how to debug what the URL is being sent down from the smart banners

Comment: @LyricalPanda No, I decided to implement the new deep linking in iOS 9.

Comment: @JamesPaolantonio and did you manage to test deep linking with iOS 9 ? I  have the exact same problem you have : not being able to test smart app banner deep link with my debug build.

Comment: @CedricSoubrie no, not from a smart banner on iOS 9.